# Set minuteStep to timepicker dynamically

Tags: jquery, timepicker

How to set minuteStep dynamically to timepicker

```
$('#end-time').timepicker({
  showInputs: false
  minuteStep: 30
});
```

Above code working properly but I want to set dynamically on my start-time changed

```
$('#start-time').on('change', function(){
  var minutes_to_add = 45;
  $('#end-time').timepicker('minuteStep', minutes_to_add);
});
```

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be

`$( "#end-time" ).timepicker('changeTime',{'minuteStep', minutes_to_add});`

```
//Call function on start-time changed
$('#start-time').on('changeTime', function(){
  updateDate(45);
}); 

//Call custom function to apply the new step
function updateDate(minutes_to_add) {
   $( "#end-time" ).timepicker('changeTime',{ 
        'minuteStep', minutes_to_add
   });
}
```

OR use `onSelect`

```
$('#start-time').timepicker({
      'minTime': '6:00am',
      'maxTime': '11:30pm',
      'onSelect': function() {
           $('#end-time').timepicker('option', 'minuteStep', 45);                        
      }
 });
```

Comment: Unexpected token , to this line   $( "#end-time" ).timepicker('change',{'minuteStep', minutes_to_add});

Comment: You might need to change events based on the plugin or library you're using for timepicker.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle to check the issue and which plugin your using for date picker?

Comment: I m using bootstrap timepicker v0.2.3